# SIP over TLS bandwidth consumption

Tags: sip, voip, tls1.2, dtls

let's say I have connection using SIPS (SIP secure) using g729 codec.
Does anyone know how many bandwidth it takes?

I know call using g729 codec 10ms is about 11Kb bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me:

- *SIP* or *SIPS* use almost the same bandwidth. It will makes **no difference**.
- The *SIP* bandwidth compared to RTP is **insignificant**.

Imagine you have a one minute call. The total exchange would be, for example:

For SIP:

```
1000 bytes for INVITE
1000 bytes for 200 OK for INVITE
500 bytes for ACK
500 bytes for BYE
500 bytes for 200 Ok for BYE
total = 3500 bytes
```

For RTP and g729, with 10ms:

```
Each of my RTP packet is 22 bytes. (not including UDP headers)
G729 payload: 10 bytes
RTP header: 12 bytes
total = 100 * 22 = 2200 bytes/second (which is 17,6kb/s)
total = 100 * 22 * 60 = 132000 bytes for a one minute call
```

For only one minute, the ratio is already

```
132000/(132000+3500) = 97,4%
3500/(132000+3500) = 2,6%
```

If you have longuer call duration, the sip related bandiwdth would drop quickly under 1%.

If you have frequent SIP messages during the calls (*like INFO*), may be you can take them into account, but this is usually not the case.

NOTE: I used an 8kbit/s G729 stream encoder instead of 11kbit/s. Just replace with your own values.

EDIT:
With usual *SRTP encryption method*, if you use *SRTP*, the encrypted payload will remain the same size. However, an additionnal **authentication tag** is usually used. With **AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80** being used, 10 bytes will be added to each packet.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i wanted to relate SIP vs RTP. I need to have a total amount in terms of bandwidht comsuption of a single call ( one call is made by SIP signaling plus RTP voice flow. In this specific case, SIP over TLS plus SRTP).

Comment: I think I have explained the *relation SIP vs RTP": ie, I have shown you how to calculate the ratio and bandwidth for a one minute call, and the same can be done for any call duration. If you wish to do it for SRTP instead (which is not in your question), just add the bits required for encryption.

Comment: Thank you again AymericM. Do you know how or where can i find techs about SRTP bits ammount? Regards

Comment: I have edited my answer to include information about SRTP overhead!